# How to import angular in bootstrap project generated by bootstrap studio?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-studio

has anyone used bootstrap studio (the drag and drop software that allows you to drag bootstrap components and modify them, then export the code) to create a nice looking bootstrap front end, but has also been able to export the code and import the angular and bootstrap libraries so that you can use the functionality of angular? For an example, If i created a landing page on bootstrap studio, how would I then add angular to my project so that I could attach the logic of a login button to one of the buttons that I created with bootstrap studio. Let me know if I can be more specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must first open some project in studio, and with system drag and drop add file with  angular code or click width right button at **OVERVIEW**  on example body and choose covert to HTML and when get of this Custom code agan click with right button and choose **edit code** and on the right middle site  you get code who you can edited.